# Issue in getting count in variable in shell script

Tags: shell, unix

I am facing issue with below command. When i am ruuning it is shell it is giving output.

```
 count=`head -92 czh_script_178.log | tail -1 | sed 's/    //'`
```

But whenb I used it in shell script then it is failing with exit 0;

Can anyone please help in this.
I am using SunOS.

Comment: `exit 0` is not an error, that is the success case. What is the error message?

Comment: #! /bin/ksh

   COMMON_DIR=/ap02p/cfdw/data_files
   LOG_DIR=$COMMON_DIR/LOG_DIR
   LOG_FILE=$LOG_DIR/script_178.log
   pattern_no=`grep -n "Query 1:" $LOG_FILE |cut -f1 -d':'`
   echo "pattern_no=$pattern_no"
   count_1=` expr $pattern_no + 6`
    echo "count=$count_1" record_count=`head -$count_1 script_178.log | tail -1 |   sed 's/    //'`
echo $record_count

Comment: Please put code in the question, not in comments.

Comment: `... it is failing with exit 0;` -- That would imply _success_.  An exit code of `0` denotes `success`, a non-zero exit code implies failure!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want line 92 without some indentation. Here's how to do that:

```
count="$(sed -n '92s/^[[:space:]]*//p' /absolute/path/to/czh_script_178.log)"
```

If the path is not absolute in the script, it will fail unless `$PWD` is the same as the directory of the log file.

Comment: I tried to use this : sed -n '92{s/^\s*//;p}' czh_script_178.log  but got below error : sed: command garbled: 92{s/^\s*//;p}

Comment: You might be using an ancient or non-standard `sed`. What does `sed --version` print?

Comment: Getting below error while checking version :                    sed: illegal option --version                                                                    SunOS 5.10 Last change: 23 Jul 1998 I got this from man grep

Comment: The script can be significantly simplified.  `sed -n '92s/^[[:space:]]*//p' file` should work basically everywhere (famous last words ... the `[[:space:]]` is POSIX so if you are on Zombie CP/M from 1977 you might not have that either).